# Unity remote debugging to android is not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-remote

Im quite new to mobile development and im having a hard time getting the debugging on the phone to work. This is the error message i get

CommandInvokationFailure: Unity Remote requirements check failed
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe forward tcp:7201 tcp:7201

Im using Unity Remote 5 on the phones
Ive tried 2 different android phones
Ive tried 2 different projects. My own and a brand new Unity Mobile template.
Ive enabled developer mode on the phones
Ive enabled USDB debugging on the phones
Ive tried disabling /renabling usb and developer mode
Ive given the phones transfer files access
The editor Unity Remote device setting in the unity project is set to Any Android Device
If i go to Build Settings i can see my phone as selectable
I can actually build and run and have the project start on the phone

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66345155

Comment: @LeoWard thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it hasn t worked. Although the 6h step "Now, switch the connection mode to "USB for Transferring files/Android Auto" im not sure about. I have no such settings so i interpreted it as disabling usb tethering.  I did get it to work earlier. I dont know how. I just tried the same thing as ive described in OP. Once it worked. Then it didnt. Then it started working again and i could swith the project on and off 2 times  untill it just stopped working. After that it hasnt worked again. Is this really how unity is supposed to do android? seems broken.

Comment: Now i actually found the "USB for Transferring files/Android Auto" . Its not in the settings but pops up in the notifications once the ca ble is connected. Still gives same result.